# Does this row permutation of stacked identity matrices have a name?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

Does this matrix have a specific name:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & 0 & & 0 \\
1 & 0 & & 0 \\
0 & 1 & & 0 \\
0 & \vdots & & 0 \\
0 & 1 & & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \ddots \\
0 & 0 & & 1 \\
0 & 0 & & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & & 1
\end{pmatrix}?$$

Comment: Could you give us some information about how this matrix came up?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom it is a submatrix of the coefficient matrix of a linear optimization problem, if the problem is the linear reformulation a few (convex) piecewise linear functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This matrix does not have a name that I know of.  However, it can be nicely written as the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) $M  = I \otimes x$ where $I$ is an identity matrix and $x$ is the column-vector $x = (1,\dots,1)^T$.

If you simply wanted to stack identity matrices, that would instead be the product $x \otimes I$.